# Transform character df into columns

Tags: r

Here's a simple one.

I have this df:

```
> str(df)
chr [1:16] "article" "198" "masterThesis" "181" "doctoralThesis" "70"
```

I need to convert it to a df like this:

```
> df
format         n
article        198
masterThesis   181
doctoralThesis 80
```

any easy one-liner and generic solution for a df like that?

Comment: Try `matrix(df, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot